# Public Key for decryption

Tags: encryption, public-key

Questions about public keys:

1. Can a PUBLIC key be created such that it can work for both encryption and decryption? (of the same object/code, of course)
2. Can a PUBLIC key be created for decryption only? (when encryption is done with the PRIVATE key). I mean, such that if used for encryption it CANNOT decrypt what it has encrypted?

Answer (score 1):

A Public key is exactly what it describes.  **Public**.  If you want a public key that both encrypts and decrypts, then it is no longer a public, nor asymmetric key.  It's just a standard symmetric key, for algorithms like AES etc.  Does this sound like what you want to do?

For your second question, a Public Key and Private Key are derived from a mathematical relationship. The RSA Private Key actually contains the Public Exponent and Modulus (among other components) that can be used to directly create the Public Key. Thus, if you have the Private Key, you also have the Public Key. Your second scenario is then not secure.

You might be interested in **signing** data using a Private Key and **verifying** the data using a Public Key.  This is common in SSL Certificates.

Comment: >> Thus, if you have the Private Key, you also have the Public Key. Your second scenario is then not good practice << Say that I have only the PUBLIC key, like may other users. If I can both sign and verify with it, then I can hack the code, generate a new hash, encrypt it with that PUBLIC and distribute it to whoever has that PUBLIC key, regardless of the PRIVATE key. Or not? Use case: secure boot of IoT.

Comment: @PaoloPiace I think you misunderstand.  Signing is performed using the **private key** and verification is performed using the **public key**.  You can't resign with the public key, doesn't work like that.

Comment: >>  You can't resign with the public key <<  Not re-sign. Just sign a new code. Anyhow, why not? Can a hacker encrypt (sign) with the PUBLIC key? The one that is spread around the users?

Comment: @PaoloPiace You are getting signing mixed up with encryption/decryption.  They are two different things...  Public Key can't be used to sign.

Comment: Thanks. I take it as you said although I don't see why not. I can encode with any number, I assume. I'm just dipping the toe in this water which means I have a lot to learn. Thanks again.

Comment: @PaoloPiace If we're talking about RSA, then we're usually talking about encrypting something with the public key (PK) and decrypting the ciphertext with the private key (SK). The mathematics of RSA permit you to use the SK for "encryption", but that doesn't provide you with the *confidentiality* property that you would expect from encryption, because anyone that has the PK which is *public* can decrypt it. There is no *confidentiality* in there. What you can do, is send the SK encryption of a message along with the message to attest that you posses the SK. This is called a digital-signature.